# JQuery Ajax POST method not working? $.post

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I'm a coding beginner in general, and I was trying to make this jquery ajax program on my own where it display the id and the password the client has typed in, but for some reason, it doesn't seem to work.

I tried reviewing the codes a few times

```html
<fieldset>
  <form>
    <label for="id">ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="id"><br>
    <label for="psswd">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="psswd"><br>
    <button id="submit">CLICK TO SUBMIT</button>
    <button type="reset">RESET</button>
  </form>
</fieldset>
<div id="result"></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var id = $("input#id").val();
    var psswd = $("input#psswd").val();
    var query = {
      id: "id",
      psswd = "psswd"       
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "process.jsp",
      data: query,
      success: function(data) {
        $("#result").html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```java
<%
  String idEg = request.getParameter("id");
  String passwordEg = request.getParameter("psswd");
  String result = "id:" + idEg + "password" + passwordEg;
  out.println(result);
%>
```

Comment: `psswd = "psswd"` needs to be changed to `psswd: "psswd"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input filed doesn't have any id. So it can not identify which value should jquery fetch from the form input field.

you should write the input filed in this way:

```
<fieldset>
  <form>
    <label for="id">ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="id" id ="id"><br>
    <label for="psswd">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="psswd" id="psswd" ><br>
    <button id="submit">CLICK TO SUBMIT</button>
    <button type="reset">RESET</button>
  </form>
</fieldset>
<div id="result"></div>
```

also be careful with form submit on click. To achieve this you have to submit the form with ajax by this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $("input#id").val();
    var psswd = $("input#psswd").val();
    var query = {
      id: "id",
      psswd: "psswd"       
    };

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "process.jsp",
      data: query,
      success: function(data) {
        $("#result").html(data);
      }
    }); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Value of query is JSON, but the way you have assigned value for key passwd is incorrect. You have used equal = instead of :

```
psswd: “psswd”
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things -

1. You have to prevent your form from being posted (submitted). Currently the submit button posts the form so you don't see the behavior in the user interface.
2. You have a typo while constructing the json payload as others have pointed out (psswd : "psswd")

Here is the demo https://jsfiddle.net/2qmL39jr/1/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();


        var id = $("input#id").val();
        var psswd = $("input#psswd").val();
        var query = {id : id,
                psswd : psswd     
        };

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "process.jsp",
            data : query,
            success : function(data){
                $("#result").html(data);
            }
        });

});
});
```